# Why click function is fired on page load with isotope an filter applied

Tags: click, load

I am experimenting something very strange. 
I have the next code that in theory is OK but instead fires the function when click on ".trigger" fires the function when the page is loaded. What can be wrong?
Please, any help to get me on the right way will be very grateful. I've been trying to find a solution all day with no success. Thank you.

```
$(function(){  
    $('.trigger').click(function(){ 
          alert('hi');
     });
});
```

EDIT 
I discovered that it only happens when the page that loads has isotope with some filter applied

Answer (score -1):

```
$(function(){  
$('.trigger').tigger("click");});
```

Comment: Hello manish. I don't understand very well your answer. Can you explain better. Thank you

Comment: Its a jquery tigger function its force to fire html dom event , when page load click event fired